Why React component is unexpectedly unmounting?
I'm implementing a React component for an account activation screen.
After reading a tutorial I decided to use a React effect to cancel the request when component is being unmounted.
The component looks like following:
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import { ServiceContainer } from '../../../services/ServiceContainer';
import { Card, Col, Container, Row, Spinner } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Link, useSearchParams } from 'react-router-dom';

function ActivateAccount(props: { serviceContainer: ServiceContainer }) {
    const { t } = useTranslation();
    const [isProgress, setIsProgress] = useState(false);
    const [isSuccess, setIsSuccess] = useState(false);

    const [searchParams, _setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();
    const email = searchParams.get("email");
    const token = searchParams.get("token");

    const abortController: AbortController = new AbortController();

    if (email == undefined || token == undefined) {

        setIsProgress(false);
        setIsSuccess(false);
    }

    function onActivationSuccess(_data: object) {

        setIsSuccess(true);
        setIsProgress(false);
    }

    function onActivationFailure(_status: number, _data: object) {

        setIsSuccess(false);
        setIsProgress(false);
    }

    useEffect(() => {

        if (email !== undefined || token !== undefined) {

            props.serviceContainer.ApiClient.ActivateAccount(email!, token!, abortController, onActivationSuccess, onActivationFailure);
        }

        return (() => {

            // Cancel API queries if unmounting
            abortController.abort();
        });
    });

    return (
        <>
            { 
                (isProgress === true &&
                    <Container>
                        // snip - show progress
                    </Container>) ||
                (isSuccess === true &&
                    <Container>
                        // snip - show success
                    </Container>) ||
                (isSuccess === false &&
                    <Container>
                        // snip - show failure
                    </Container>)
            }
        </>
    );            
}

export { ActivateAccount }

What happens is that immediately upon entering the screen, the effect's "destructor" gets called and request is cancelled.
Initially my function's return was split into three if's:
// ...

if (isProgress) {

    return (
        // ...
    )
} else if (isSuccess) {

    return (
        // ...
    )
} else {

    return (
        // ...
    )
}

I thought that replacing the whole component's contents causes the unmount, but after replacing ifs with the switch being effectively a boolean expression (so that root of the component does not change when the mode changes), the effect's "destructor" is still being called and request gets terminated immediately.
So for the question:
Why effect's "destructor" gets called immediately? How should I implement cancellation of the request in the proper way, so that request gets cancelled only if the component actually gets unmounted? (e.g. user leaves the screen)

Are you using ?

@ruakh Yes, why?

You're missing useEffect's dependency array, it's the second argument of the function and dictates when it's cleanup function should fire.
If there isn't a dependency array, it fires on every render.
If there is one, if fires whenever an item in it changes. Because of this you will need to memoize things like abortController and possibly props.serviceContainer
// this also has a dependency array, but it's empty so it will never change
const abortController = useMemo(() => new new AbortController()), []);

useEffect(() => {
  // moved these into the useEffect so we don't get a new one each render
  function onActivationSuccess(_data: object) {
    setIsSuccess(true);
    setIsProgress(false);
  }

  function onActivationFailure(_status: number, _data: object) {
    setIsSuccess(false);
    setIsProgress(false);
  }

  if (email !== undefined || token !== undefined) {
    props.serviceContainer.ApiClient.ActivateAccount(
      email!,
      token!,
      abortController,
      onActivationSuccess,
      onActivationFailure,
    );
  }

  return (() => {
    // Cancel API queries if unmounting
    abortController.abort();
  });
}, [ // added dependency array
  email,
  token,
  props.serviceContainer,
  abortController,
  setIsSuccess,
  setIsProgress,
  ]);


While your answer is obviously valuable, with the StrictMode mentioned by @ruakh, the destructor still was being called - even with the changes you suggested. I'm wondering, how should I implement this component so that it still works in the Strict Mode, because as I understand, failing to do so makes it non-conforming to the React's requirements of components behaving predictably when created and torn down continuously...

It shouldn't matter that it gets cancelled once, and strict mode only does that in dev mode, not in the production build.
